# Font is not getting applied in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am sending an email newsletter.

Some how the font `Novecentowide-Medium.otf` is not getting applied in any heading.

the original font in PSD looks like

[image]

When i send a test email it looks like

[image]

**The html code for font is**

```
<h2 style="font-family: 'novecento_widemedium'; font-weight:400; padding-left:70px;">Transforming<span>Drones</span></h2>
```

Comment: fonts are **not supported** in email you should use default system fonts

Comment: I agree with @Vitorinofernandes,  How about an image of this text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect your opentype font in css:

```
@font-face 
{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Arial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(path/to/font/Novecentowide-Medium.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Or use standart format **ttf**:

```
@font-face 
{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Arial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(path/to/font/Novecentowide-Medium.ttf); /* Pay attention to extension */
}
```

Comment: This is correct, I believe. But make sure that this is posted within the `head` section of the email. More information can be found here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/